# Javascript Update mysql Row on Bootstrap modal open

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I think that I already formulated my problem in topic title.

I got eCommerce shop with products in grid view. For each Item I have unique modal with product information and more.

Products are stored in MySQL database. And got views(Count, how many users have viewed this product)

I want to Update MySQL row, when Modal is opened.

But at this point I got 2 problems:
1.It updates value even if modal is not opened.(Page simply loads)
2.It updates all product's views count.(I think it's because 1.problem)

For each product I have unique ID and class(Will copy only starting code, because all modal is big)

```
<div class="modal fade shop_item_<?php echo $item['id'];?>" id="shop_item_<?php echo $item['id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="width:100%">
```

And this is how I'm trying to update views(This code are located right after modal):

```
<script>
    $('#shop_item_<?php echo $item['id'];?>"').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      <?php
      $id = $item['id'];

      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT views FROM shop_items WHERE id='$id'");
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
      foreach ($result as $views){
        $newviews = $views['views'] +1;
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE shop_items SET views = '$newviews' WHERE id='$id'");
        $stmt->execute();
      }
     ?>
</script>
```

Comment: put common class name for all the modal and for you button or ink to open the modal put the class name common. Define a click event for that comman class name and get the attribute if the ID field which will be unique not common. So that you can track which modal get activated based on the ID.
Never put unique class name for a same group of components. Because we can define operations for those group of component based on the class and identify them uniquely based on the ID. Your problem will be solved when you can utilize both class and ID in intended way

Comment: @webDev I don't understand how does this solve that all product views updates?

Comment: okay so when ever you click on a element to open the modal.... you need to get id = .....attr('id') of the modal which will have the id of the record. Fire a ajax call and update the record based on the id stored on the ID attribute of the modal. first of all tell me how you open the modal do you have button or link inside loop?

Comment: @webDev I found out that problem is somewhere here "$('.shop_item22_<?php echo $item['id'];?>"').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {" becouse shop_item22 don't even exist, but update function still working

Comment: yes thats why I am saying use class name for the actions on JS not ID. because its not a good idea to repeat JS code and method which does not have much difference. Just tract the current item_id clicked. See my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you comment, what you can do is simply put item id and HTMl attribute ID

See all the IDs and classes that I have put. You need only one Javascript method for a grup of same modals.

```
<!-- Inside a loop -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg open_modal" id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $item['id']; ?>">Open Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="width:100%">
    .......
    .......
    .......
</div>
<!------------------>
```

One single JS method to update the record based on the modal opened

```
<script>
    $('.open_modal').click(function () {
        var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
        //get all other data based on this ID and also get updated one from modal
        //make a ajax call to update the record base on this item_id
    })

</script>
```

**Assumptions:** I assume that you have lots of modal created via loop and you want to update each modal record based on which one you gonna open.